# Should I Remove the initial symbols of Module?

Tags: programming, scoping, memory

Often we use Module to construct complicate function. Consider that Module create new vars every time we run the function, should I remove the initial values at the end of Module-function?Or should I worry about it?

I never thought of this problem until I browse [this question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78332/memory-problem-with-modules-and-ndsolve) the first comment under the question suggested 'Try ending the Module with result =plapla; Clear[...]; result'. However,when I test Module on my Mma9, it cleared the value of initial values automatically. That is to say, I have no way to recover the initial values of initial vars after I run the Module(If I didn't Print value out). for example,define:

```
f[x_] :=
Module[{a, b},
Print@ToString@a;
a = Range[1000]; a[[4]]
]
```

run f[2] it print the initial symbols a$$4120, however run a$4120 it returns a$4120 as if it had not been set value.
So it's not necessary to explicitly Remove the initial symbols of Module at the end of Module?Right?

Comment: Right, those variables have `Attribute` `Temporary` which means you don't have to worry.

Comment: It's only an issue when the local smbols get used in a way that leaks frfom `Module` (not your situation) or when `DownValues` are placed on them.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Actually, when I remember it right, `DownValues` by themselves are not a problem, as long as that symbol is not referenced from the outside. So, this is Ok: `Module[{f}, f[1] = 1;f[1]]`, while this leads to a leak for `f`: `Module[{g}, Module[{f}, g[x_] := f[x]; f[1] = 1;];g[1]]`, even though `g` has been later collected. I mentioned this case [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/debugging-memory-leaks/6179#6179).

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin Yes, good point. I thought there was some extra issue involved but did not recall what it was.

Comment: Related: "[Module trash collection behaviour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37082/280)."