# Why does `... := With[{var = ...}, ...]` create `var$`?

Tags: scoping, memory

**EDIT**
This issue is specifically different from the "duplicate" question. The creation of variables in the active context during parsing is of no surprise and is the expected behavior.

What I'm observing is the creation of a *temporary* variable which is not automatically deleted. The following constructs:

```
f[x_] := With[{a = x}, dostuff];
```

or more generally

```
f[x_] := Module[{a = g[x]}, dostuff];
```

create not only `a` in the global namespace, *but also* `a$`:

```
?a$
```

> ```
> Global`a$
> Attributes[a$] = {Temporary}
> ```

Should I be concerned, is this a memory leak, is there specific reasoning behind this, etc?
**END EDIT; original question below**

Starting with a fresh kernel I type:

```
myFunc[x_] := With[{g = x}, Print[5]];
? Global`*
```

Among the returned symbols I find, not only the expected `myFunc`, `g`, and `x`. There is also  **the temporary in attribute `g$`**. Why is this happening? Is this indicating some sort of memory leak?

The implicit question is also "how to avoid this and keep my packages clean if this is indeed the case".

m_goldberg asked for a more realistic use case; I'm more than happy to oblige:

```
ImportBIG[names_List, p0_Real, a0_Real, depol_Real, fourierFunc_]:=
    With[
        {strm = OpenRead[#, BinaryFormat->True] & /@ names , n = Length[names],
            fft = (Exp[2 I a0 Degree - 2 I Pi (-1+(ConstantArray[0.I,20]+Range[20]))2/20])/20
        },
        Block[{...},
            Do[assoc[idx] = ReadString[strm[[idx]]];
                dostuff;, {idx, n}]
            (* more do loops with {idx, n} *)
            Do[assoc[idx, "Rho"] = With[{f = assoc[idx, "Fourier"]},
                ArcTan[-I Sqrt[1 - 4 Abs[f]^2] + 2 Im[f]] / (1 - 2 Re[f])]], {idx, n}]
        ]
    ]
```

As you can see, I'm using `With` as an idiomatic way to have constants in my functions, also to shorten on keystrokes to make code more readable, to cut down on repeated evaluation of the same thing (such as `Length[names]`), etc.

In this case, of course, the offending temporary variables are `n$`, `fft$`, `strm$` and `f$`.

Comment: Can you give an example where this kind of construct is needed? I ask because formal arguments (`x` in your case) have semantics very close to what `With` provides and I don't see why you need to use `With` like you show in your question.

Comment: Overeager localization?  This is one of the ways name conflicts are avoided e.g. in `With[{x = 5}, Function[x, x^2]]` where one of the two `x`s must be renamed to prevent conflict between the `With` and the `Function`.  In your example this doesn't seem to be needed but happens anyway.  That's much better than when it is needed but doesn't happen.  It doesn't cause harm.  I don't know why the `Temporary` isn't removed (as it is with `Module` ones), but it has been like this forever.

Comment: Related: "[Module trash collection behaviour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37082/280)", "[Reducing memory usage in an extended Mathematica session](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6867892/590388)."

Comment: @m_goldberg I've added a more involved example.

Comment: Related: [(119403)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119403). Also [(20766)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766), [(42351)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42351), [(91917)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91917).

Comment: No, I don't think you should be concerned.  It's not a memory leak if `var$` has no value.  It's not causing any problems.  It doesn't produce an unlimited amount of pollution like numbered `Module` variables would since the name is always the same: `var$`, instead of `var$1`, `var$2`, `var$3` ... with no end to it. While the question can be interesting theoretically, I see no practical issues.

Comment: @Szabolcs I guess it's some sort of answer to my question. Thanks!